# Как открыть сетевую папку с паролем в Windows?

Tags: python, windows, smb

Мне нужно открыть сетевую папку в Проводнике из Python-скрипта.

Я умею открывать сетевые папки без пароля через startfile:

```
os.startfile(r"\\192.168.1.2\folder")
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно открыть сетевую папку с паролем, и тогда startfile выдаёт ошибку:

```
OSError: [WinError 86] Сетевой пароль указан неверно: '\\\\192.168.1.3\\folder'
```

Во-первых, где мне указать сетевой пароль?

Во-вторых, можно ли как-то вывести стандартное окошко ввода пароля Проводника и позволить пользователю ввести пароль в Проводник, не трогая Python-скрипт? Я пробовал открывать `explorer.exe` через `subprocess.Popen`, но запускаемый Проводник просто игнорирует второй аргумент и открывает папку пользователя «Документы» вместо сетевой папки.

Comment: я бы сначала замапил эту сетевую папку в диск: `net use ...`, а потом открывал используя этот диск...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493699/access-remote-files-on-server-with-smb-protocol-python3

Comment: @MaxU мапить это не круто

Comment: @0andriy мне не нужно файлы в питоне читать, мне нужно папку в Проводнике открыть

Comment: Отсюда инфа никак не поможет: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/k7mkg/python_32_and_accessing_a_network_location/ ?

Comment: А если попробовать smb://логин:пароль@хост. Ведь это же URL. Может поймёт.

Comment: @strawdog после win32net.NetUseAdd os.startfile начинает работать нормально, так что наверно можно в ответы) Хотя в идеале я всё равно хотел бы увидеть стандартное окошко Проводника с вводом пароля

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис такие URL обычно используется в линуксах, а винда такое не понимает

Answer (score 1):

Используй библиотеку pysmb. В ней можно указывать логин и пароль для авторизации.

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
conn = SMBConnection(userid, password, client_machine_name, remote_machine_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
conn.connect(server_ip, 139)
filelist = conn.listPath('shared_folder_name', '/')
```

Для попытки ввода другого логина или пароля оберни код в try except.

Comment: Мне нужно открыть именно Проводник